# iPhone SDK: IBAction

Tags: iphone, uikit, interface-builder

I have a situation where I'd like a button to respond to two different IBAction methods. Is there a way that I can force a particular method first? When I look at the buttons connections in IB they are in the correct order, but they consistently perform in the opposite order.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the two different methods live in different classes. This newb does not know (yet) how to have a method in one class call another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting all the connections in IB then reconnecting in the order I require seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, but why not just call one action from the other?